# git thinking file is unmodified(possibly visual studio)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, git, github

So when I try to do `git add` git doesn't include it because it thinks it is unmodified. But just 10 seconds before, I modified it in visual studio C# 2010 express and saved it. Although git still thinks it is unmodified. But if I edit it with notepad++(I'm sure any other program would work too) it will add it to the list and commit it. SO is there an option in visual studio or git? This is really annoying as it also includes the compiled dll which I can't edit.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suspect it has to do with Visual Studio not updating the file's last modified time when you save it.  Look for options within Visual Studio relating to that.

Answer (score 1):

One way to work around that is to install the Git [Source Control Provider](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/63a7e40d-4d71-4fbb-a23b-d262124b8f4c), which will be mmore aware of any file modification with a solution.

[image: pending change view]

Its pending change view should be accurate.